# New manage property not returning to search results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-property, crawled-property, crawl-external-content

I am working with  sharepoint 2013 on premise. 
I attached new crawled properties to managed properties (existing managed properties and new one ) and couldn't get any result using it- i ticked the new managed property aa retrievable, safe etc.

It does not matter from which content source i add the mp - i don't retrieve it..like the sql is  full or mp not really retrievable / safe

Old data is updated fine
I ran full crawl - restarted the the service and the crawl server
At the moment reset index is not possible (6 website using it) 
Out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Check if there are errors in the crawl log.
2. Check if there are values under the crawled property which is mapped to the managed property.
3. Use the search format below in the search box.

Managedproperty:keywords

4. Create a new page, add the search box web part and search result web part in the page and check if the same issue will occur.

Answer (score 0):

After allot of discussions with the   IT department, we decided to clear search configuration.. And results started coming through
The article that really helped :
http://www.jonthenerd.com/2017/09/16/managed-props-and-config-cache/